# Receiving touch events in hidden UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Is it possible in some way to receive and respond to touch events from a UIView that is not visible. I tried -- as well as read from the Apple docs -- that simply setting 'hidden' will not work. I'm looking for an alternative to achieve the same effect.

> A hidden view disappears from its window and does not receive input events. It remains in its superview’s list of subviews, however, and participates in autoresizing as usual. Hiding a view with subviews has the effect of hiding those subviews and any view descendants they might have. This effect is implicit and does not alter the hidden state of the receiver’s descendants.

Comment: You can do it using hit-test munging. But why do you want to? The whole idea makes no sense. If the user can't see a view, the user can't touch that view. That's the reason for this rule.

Comment: @matt We are rendering the UIView to a texture and displaying it on a quad in OpenGL. However we'd still like the UIView to respond to the inputs to control the view.

Answer (score 2):

if a view has set userInteractionEnabled to YES it will be touchable when hidden. Try to experiment with UIButton for example.

Answer (score -1):

Make it transparent, not hidden (with alpha set to 0).  If that doesn't work, make it nearly transparent (alpha set to 0.1).

Comment: Changing the alpha unfortunately affects the image that is rendered to texture, showing it as transparent as well.

Comment: Do that after you render.

Comment: Or just make a different UIView that is the same size and location to be the hit tester.  Make that one transparent.

Comment: The alpha toggle is clever and almost works, unfortunately diminishing the alpha too low disables input response automatically, any higher and the layer is still visible.

Comment: First, setting alpha = 1 would be equivalent to completely opaque. Second, views that have an alpha of 0 do not receive touch events. This answer is totally off on all fronts.

Comment: @mbradber there are many ways to make only some things alpha